# Deploying Event Layout : Invalid field:NAME in related list:ManyWhoRelatedPeopleList

Tags: deployment, event

I'm deploying a Page Layout for Event from GitHub to my integration org.

The deployment fails with this error: `Invalid field:NAME in related list:ManyWhoRelatedPeopleList`

The relevant XML from the source layout is:

```
<relatedLists>
    <fields>NAME</fields>
    <fields>TYPE</fields>
    <relatedList>ManyWhoRelatedPeopleList</relatedList>
</relatedLists>
```

Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is the target org does not have  `Allow Users to Relate Multiple Contacts to Tasks and Events enabled`

[image]

If you check the box, this exposes several fields and in particular, the related list `ManyWhoRelatedPeopleList`.  Thus, the deployment will work. This related list is called `Name` in the Page Layout UX

[image]